# Is it permissible for standard library implementation to have class definition that is different from the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

The following code successfully compiled with clang and MSVC but fail to compile in GCC 6.1.0.

```
#include <memory>

template<typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
T* test(R(T::*)(Args...) const)
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    using T = std::shared_ptr<int>;
    T* p = test(&T::get);
}
```

with the following error message

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:13:16: error: invalid conversion from 'std::__shared_ptr<int, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>*' to 'T* {aka std::shared_ptr<int>*}' [-fpermissive]
     T* p = test(&T::get);
            ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is that libstdc++ implemented `std::shared_ptr` by inheriting member function `get` from a base class `std::__shared_ptr`.

In the C++ standard **20.8.2.2 Class template shared_ptr**, it specifies the class definition of std::shared_ptr class with all the member functions of that class.

My question is whether the implementation must at least provide all public class members as defined in the standard inside the standard class?  Is it allowed to provide the member functions by inheriting from base class as implemented in libstdc++?

Comment: **17.6.5.11 Derived classes [derivation]**
_An implementation may derive any class in the C++ standard library from a class with a name reserved to the implementation_. Footnote 188 (n3797) might be of interest too.

Comment: Hmya, you also won't find a Lock_policy template argument in the standard.  It is the kind of thing that happens when compiler library writers either implement a class before the standard is approved or make it practical for real world usage.  Not including a locking policy in the standard was a pretty controversial decision.  Real world overrides.

Comment: I'm not very good in reading the standard. My understanding of this sentence is that the implementation is allowed to inherit from a base class but it does not specify whether it is allow/disallow to provide the class member functions in standard class thru inheriting from base class.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler is wrong. `std::shared_ptr<int>::get` is a member function of `std::shared_ptr<Int>` regardless of how it got there, and `T` in the template is `std::shared_ptr<int>`.

Comment: You might also want to take a look in the MSVC standard headers, they're not exactly the same as the standard, either. For example, their implementation of `std::exception` allows it to be constructed from a C string, which `exception.what()` will return; to my knowledge, none of the classes derived from it (such as `std::logic_error` and `std::runtime_error`) even override `what()`, they just pass their ctors' string parameter to the MS-specific `exception` ctor that takes a C string to set `what()`'s output.  What matters is that it offers the behaviour specified by the standard.

Comment: Additionally, most of their implementations of standard classes derive from hidden classes, more directly paralleling GCC's behaviour.

Comment: I think it is okay for implementation to provide extra constructor or method and for the implementation to derive from a hidden class but the implemented standard class should at least has all the public members defined in standard.  If the standard says that there is a `get` member in the `shared_ptr` class definition, can I expect the correct behavior to be able to compile the code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard's specification for types and their members is normative text, unless it *explicitly* says otherwise. As such, an implementation is required to follow that... to the extent that an implementation is required to follow *anything* from the standard.

And that extent is the "as if" rule. Namely, the implementation is allowed to do what it wants so long as the type behaves "as if" it were done as specified. The reason the standard has specific language stating that types can be derived from arbitrary, implementation-provided base classes is because that is something which a user can detect. It's visible behavior (through implicit conversions and the like) and therefore the standard would have to make an exception in order to allow for it.

Inheriting a member is *almost* the same thing as declaring it in your main class. Indeed, the only way I know of to tell the difference is to do what you did here: use template argument deduction rules. Even though you can specify the member as `Derived::get`, if it really comes from some base class, the compiler will know.

However, [member.functions] comes to GCC's rescue here. It has explicit language allowing standard library implementations to add additional overloads to a class. Because of that, your use of `std::shared_ptr<int>::get` here is not well-defined behavior. Indeed, footnote 187 clarifies this:

> Hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type.

That's merely a footnote, but the intent seems clear: you cannot rely on any particular implementation to return any particular type of member pointer. Even if you applied a cast operation to the right signature, there is no guarantee that it would work.

So while the class definition in the standard library is normative text, [member.functions] makes it clear that the *only* thing you can guarantee about those definitions is that you can call those functions using the arguments provided. Anything else, like getting member pointers, is implementation-defined.

Comment: I think footnote 187 should be read in the context of [member.function] 2 and (2.1).  

2. An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures **within a class**:  
(2.1) — by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature;187  

My understanding is that the implementation can provide member function `void get(int = 0)`;  
if the std specify member function  `void get()`  
Hence footnote 187 clarify that the type of member get is not specified. 
It can be `void(T::*)(int)` or `void(T::*)()` but isn't it must still be **within a class**?

Comment: if the test function above is returning the `sizeof(Args...)`, then footnote 187 make it implementation defined.

Comment: @kwanti: The footnote doesn't say that the *signature* is implementation defined; it said that the whole type would be.

Comment: Since this is the only answer I will accept it (thank you for answering).  It is unbelievable that the standard tell us we can't use the member function pointer of a standard class for anything because we don't know it's type.  Am I correct to say that this implies that if I use std::function to bind to a member function pointer of any standard class, I can't expect it to be portable because type (including the function signature?) is implementation defined?

Comment: @kwanti: Pretty much. You can always use a lambda to create the effect of a member pointer call.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what type of member function of standard class we got when C++ has reflection. :-)